# .htaccess rewrite conditions for https:// pre tag subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, https, subdomain, wildcard

### I need some extra codes into my .htaccess what configures this correct http request for https too!

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

#### My problem

Now it gets the /sponsor tag only if i type the example with http:

> **GOOD:** This is working: http://example.mydomain.com result is:
>   http://example.mydomain.com/sponsor/example
>
> **BAD:** This isn't working: https://example.mydomain.com result is:
>   https://example.mydomain.com/

## Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Cross-site post on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/120353/htaccess-rewrite-conditions-for-https-pre-tag-subdomains

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteCond ℅{REQUEST_URI} !^/sponsor/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/sponsor/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I removed the `℅{HTTPS} off` condition from your rule as it was only accepting http urls and added `℅{REQUEST_URI}` to avoid rewiring to the same location.

Comment: :( i am getting this: 403.shtml / sponsor into the code

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

If i open the link with HTTPS https://test.mydomain.com than i am getting just: https://test.mydomain.com

But if i open the link with HTTP http://test.mydomain.com i am getting the correct wanted url: https://test.mydomain.com/sponsor/test

Comment: I still need help, any ideas?